# Grep from one long line

Tags: bash, grep

I have a long JSON line containing a lot of data which I want to grep from without seeing the other data.

Content:

```
28.1270450678417,&quot;app_delay_avrg&quot;:612,&quot;app_delay_max&quot;:4348,&quot;app_delay_min&quot;:0,&quot;data_in_sum&quot;:88459347,&quot;data_out_sum&quot;:5947410,&quot;rps_avrg&quot;:19242,&quot;rps_max&quot;:46843,&quot;rps_min&quot;:120,&quot;success_sum&quot;:32948,&quot;errors_sum&quot;:12115,&quot;timeout_errors_sum&quot;:779,&quot;network_errors_sum&quot;:0,&quot;started_at_date&quot;:&quot;04/13/2016&quot;,&quot;started_at_time&quot;:&quot;07:12 AM&quot;,&quot;share_box_info&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:1261233,&quot;result_url&quot;:&quot;http://loader.io/reports/ff4b7ca58e569af5a9650b9a2b856f39/results/6b4e3ae3f83407c91b10402b2e4231c6&quot;,&quot;endpoint_widget_url&quot;:&quot;//share.loader.io/reports/ff4b7ca58e569af5a9650b9a2b856f39/widget/results/6b4e3ae3f83407c91b10402b2e4231c6&quot;,&quot;short_url
```

Command: `root@user:/home/user# cat data.txt | grep app_delay_max\&quot\;:`

Result (excepts) and the grepped content is marked as red in terminal.

```
28.1270450678417,&quot;app_delay_avrg&quot;:612,&quot;***app_delay_max&quot;:4348***,&quot;app_delay_min&quot;:0,&quot;data_in_sum&quot;:88459347,&quot;data_out_sum&quot;:5947410,&quot;rps_avrg&quot;:19242,&quot;r
```

How can I only get this output and remove the other content?

```
 app_delay_max&quot;:4348
```

Comment: the "Content" is the whole input? (is this the entire content of data.txt or are there other lines that do not contains `app_delay_max&quot;`) ?

Comment: i suggest you to put your content of `data.txt` into a `.ini` file. then read it using python script. it would be easier.

Comment: or, write your json in plain JSON format text, then you can read it using python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
grep -o 'app_delay_max&quot;:[0-9]*' data.txt
```

> -o, --only-matching
>                Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Comment: @poncha Indeed, but I didn't want to change the initial regex to fit the question.  Thanks

Comment: the op gave sample output.. anyway feel free to roll back my change if you like ;)

Comment: How can I only get the values after `;:`  ?

Comment: @user3580316 pipe the output of this through `cut -d: -f2` and it would leave just the number